# Pretending that telegram bot is typing?

Tags: bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

How can I make a bot to pretend that it is typing a message?

The following text appears in the chat when the bot pretend to type:

[image]

I use the python [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) framework but a suggestion for the native Telegram API would be also helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I seriously suggest using the `python-telegram-bot` library which has an extensive Wiki.  The solution for what you want is described in [code snippets](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#send-a-chat-action).

You can manually send the action:

```
bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id, action=telegram.ChatAction.TYPING)
```

Or create a decorator which can then be used on any function you wish to show that action on whilst processing:

```
from functools import wraps
from telegram import (ChatAction)

def send_typing_action(func):
    """Sends typing action while processing func command."""

    @wraps(func)
    def command_func(update, context, *args, **kwargs):
        context.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=update.effective_message.chat_id, action=ChatAction.TYPING)
        return func(update, context,  *args, **kwargs)

    return command_func

@send_typing_action
def my_handler(update, context):
    pass # Will send 'typing' action while processing the request.
```

Comment: But, "typing" status goes away after few second even if processing the request isn't finished! How to get "typing" for longer time?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the `/sendChatAction` endpoint only lasts for 5 seconds and then stays off until the bot sends a response. In other words, making additional requests doesn't turn the typing indicator back on afaict.

Answer (score 1):

On Node Telegraf

```
ctx.replyWithChatAction('typing')
```

Answer (score 0):

For aiogram module you can use types.Message built in method `answer_chat_action`.

```
from aiogram import types

async def answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer_chat_action("typing")
    await message.answer("Hi!")
```

[Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendchataction) is another action types such as *upload_photo*, *record_video_note* and so on. And [here](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html?highlight=answer_chat_action#aiogram.types.message.Message.answer_chat_action) is aiogram documentation.

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html?highlight=answer_chat_action#aiogram.types.message.Message.answer_chat_action link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

To make your bot pretend that it is typing less than 5 seconds use code like this:

```py
await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id, 'typing')
await asyncio.sleep(5)
await message.answer(text)
```

To make your bot pretend that it is typing, and you need to do it longer than 5 seconds, do something like this:

```py
async def keep_typing_while(chat_id, func):
    cancel = { 'cancel': False }

    async def keep_typing():
        while not cancel['cancel']:
            await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id, 'typing')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

    async def executor():
        await func()
        cancel['cancel'] = True

    await asyncio.gather(
        keep_typing(),
        executor(),
    )
```

And execute it like this:

```py
answer = {}

async def openai_caller():
    local_answer = await get_openai_completion(user_context.get_messages())
    answer['role'] = local_answer['role']
    answer['content'] = local_answer['content']

await keep_typing_while(message.chat.id, openai_caller)

await message.answer(answer['content'])
```

Also, instead of

```py
await bot.send_chat_action(chat_id, 'typing')
```

you can try:

```py
await message.answer_chat_action("typing")
```